# How do you run optimized ClojureScript output?

Tags: clojurescript

I have a ClojureScript project that I was compiling in "dev" mode, with no compiler optimizations. I would "run" it like this, from HTML, a described in the [quick start docs](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start).

```
<script src="/js/out/goog/base.js"></script>
<script src="/js/out/main.js"></script>
<script> goog.require("myapp.mymodule"); </script>
```

The `main.js` file is the one generated by the ClojureScript compiler, from `.cljs` source files.

Now I have a second profile in my Leiningen project that enables advanced compiler optimizations. As expected, `main.js` changes to include a lot of obfuscated Javascript.  But now the `require` line above fails:

```
Error: goog.require could not find: myapp.mymodule
```

I also tried marking one of my functions with `:export`:

```
(defn ^:export foo [] ...)
```

But the [docs](https://clojurescript.org/reference/advanced-compilation) don't mention where that symbol will be, and I don't see it on `window` or anywhere else.

So, how does the HTML call into the compiled ClojureScript to get the program started?

Here are the relevant sections of my project.clj

```
:cljsbuild {
  :builds {
    :app {
      :source-paths ["src/main/clj"]
      :compiler {
        :output-to "target/resources/public/js/out/main.js"
        :output-dir "target/resources/public/js/out"
        :asset-path "/js/out"
      }
    }
  }
}
...
:profiles {
  :uberjar {
    :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]       
    :omit-source true        
    :cljsbuild {
      :builds {
        :app {             
         :compiler {:optimizations :advanced
                    :pretty-print false}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And to compile with the optimizations I ran:

```
lein with-profile uberjar cljsbuild once
```

Comment: Can you share your complete project.clj file?

Comment: I added the cljsbuild parts to my question. Is that enough?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some compiler options, like `:output-to` and `:source-path`.
You can find the list of options at https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options.

If you want to see what a minimal production build looks like, create a new empty project using `lein new cljsbuild-template <project-name>`

Comment: Those options are there. Maybe you missed it because my config is split in two parts. I think I found the problem now. Unfortunately I had missed another error, happening before the require error. My code was trying to refer to a JS variable on the window, defined outside of clojurescript. So I need to reference it like `(aget js/window "foo")` not `js/window.foo` for it to work with advanced optimizations.